# iOS 9 Pantalla Splash siempre negra

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

La pantalla de inicio (splash) de la aplicación en iOs, siempre lo muestra negra. Tengo configurado en el proyecto: 
**Targets/General/App Icons and Launch Images/launch Screen File.**

Pero al ejecutar, siempre la pantalla es **negra**.

Comment: Al desplegar en el simulador, es necesario eliminar la aplicación, hacer un Clean al proyecto e ir al menú Simulator/Reset Content And Settings. Y desplegar la aplicación nuevamente.

Comment: Hacer un clean de vez en cuando te puede ayudar. La pantalla negra es el LaunchScreen.xib de tu proyecto @Jhonattan. Debes personalizar tu mismo esa pantalla.

Answer (score 1):

Probar las siguientes opciones:

1. Verificar que el archivo de Launch Screen se haya añadido en: TARGET/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources
2. Al desplegar en el simulador, es necesario eliminar la aplicación, hacer un Clean al proyecto e ir al menú 

   **Simulator/Reset Content And Settings.**
   Y desplegar la aplicación nuevamente.
3. Si estas desplegando en un iPhone/iPad, eliminar la aplicación, reiniciar el dispositivo y volver a compilar la app.

Esto funcionó para mi

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un problema común con el iOS 9.

Veo que agregaste una respuesta pero en mi caso esta fue la solución:

Dentro del folder `Assets.xcassets`, click al signo "+" para usar la opción `Import from Project` donde se seleccionas los .png.